# Do I need to call "super.XXX" whenever I override a method?

Tags: java, android, overriding

Say, if I don't call `super.onPause` in a override method from superclass `Activity`, I would get an error when `onPause()` is called. But errors don't show up when I have no `super.XXX` calls in methods (`onCreate`, `onStartCommand`, ...) of a class derived from `Service`.

So on what conditions should I call `super.XXX` in a override method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation tells you](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) that you need to call `onPause` if you derive the `Activity` class:

> *Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.*

The `Service` docs don't require that in the [`onStartCommand` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)).

In general (not specifically in Android stuff), when you derive, you should call through to the superclass's methods unless you know you shouldn't. It's a decision that needs to be case-by-case, but the default (I'd say) would be that you do it.

Answer (score 0):

> So on what conditions should I call super.XXX in a override method?

It is not possible to give a useful answer to this.  It entirely depends on the intended purpose and behavior of the override method and the method being overridden.

If you don't know, you need to do one or more of the following:

- read the javadocs for the method,
- look at examples of classes that implement the method, and / or
- look at the code of the method you are overriding.

In this particular case, the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) gives a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must call them if the manual says so as @t-j-crowder said.

[it says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29)

> Derived classes must call through to
>   the super class's implementation of
>   this method. If they do not, an
>   exception will be thrown.

If not, then the reasoning is that if you are calling a function, do you want the 'normal' behaviour to be started?

For instance, if you override the `onKeyDown()` You could do something after a certain key is pressed (e.g. 'back'). Then you have the choice:

- If you want the normal action of 'back' to be executed, call the super
- If you DON'T want to run the normal action, don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

Client code can only know subclass `Activity` (call it `MyActivity`), Client code cannot know `Activity`. However, `MyActivity` can know its base class Activity.

If the overridden method `onPause()` is same as its base class, you don’t need to override it explicitly.

Comment: @ZhengZhiren: StackOverflow is done in English. (All: Google's translation: "Maybe you should answer my question")

Answer (score 0):

Based on Android document: Unlike the activity lifecycle callback methods, you are not required to call the superclass implementation of these callback methods for service lifecycle callback methods.